# Split one big class on sub-classes

Tags: java

I have a generic question and I don't understand how create what I want. 
I writing a basic program they can access to one database an do some SQL request, etc. But at the moment I have one big class with all SQL for all the tables from the database. And I want slipt this class in different classes for make the code more easy to read and implement stuff. I think the best solution is create one subclass for each table on the database and on for this class put all the methods related on this class. But later I don't understand how I can call this methods from the class. Because for access to the database I create an object DataBase on the main application and if I want call a method just I do a `database.methodIWant()`.

At the moment I have:

- `DataBase` (this class have all the methods for the databases) extends `DataBaseUtil`
- `DataBaseUtil` (this class contain all methods and information for connect to the database)

and I crate the database object with `DataBase db = new DataBase();`

And I want something like:

- `DataBase` (this class have all the methods for the databases) extends `DataBaseUtil`
- `DataBaseUtil` (this class contain all methods and information for connect to the database)

and classes for example:

- `DogSQL` (all the methods for the table dog on the database)
- `CatSQL` (all the methods for the table cat on the database)

and I create the database object with `DataBase db = new DataBase();` and call methods like `db.methodFromDogSQL();`

I don't understand how do this. I don't understand if a need use abstract, interface, inheritance for this or which is the best implementation for this. I'm starting and my knowledge in java is a bit basic, so I want learn how do this type of stuff.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that you still need a master DataBase class even after the split, why not have `dogdb.someMethod(); catdb.otherMethod();` instead of one `db` object for both? Also, are you sure all your SQL operations will affect only one table at a time? (most properly-normalized databases require join queries to do anything interesting)

Comment: In the main class. I have one object DB and this object call the methods. My database I have 3 tables (room (id,name), pets(id, room_id, name), friend(id, animal_id, name)). So first I select a room and now I can now how many animals we have in that room, so if I want know the owner of one animal I can do it. But I only want have DB on the main application for all the program, because in the constructor I create the database and I make the connection and I handle all the request. But I want split the class for one for each table for more readable code and more easy implement more methods

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for using *sub*classes here, Dog and Cat should not be derived from `Database` (in fact, this would result in a typical example of how to **not** to use inheritance).

Instead, you could have the Create/Read/Update/Delete methods of the classes `Dog` or `Cat` just have a parameter of type `DataBase` (or `IDataBase`, an interface, if you want to be able to mock the database object for testing). For example, there should not be a method in `DataBase` like `db.SelectDog(int Id)`, only a (maybe static) method in the class `Dog` like `Dog.Select(IDatabase db, int Id`). That method could return a `Dog` object, which corresponds to a row in your Dog table.

The "Dog.Select" method may contain the SQL code needed and call some general methods of `IDataBase` for selecting data, but in no way should your database class have knowledge about the SQLs needed for specific business objects.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you study Inversion of Control and the dependency injection pattern. Take a look at this [Martin Fowler article on dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). Using an IoC container will help you break up your class into more manageable components and make your solution less brittle than it is now.